# skylanders swap force wii accessing 2 players

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

How do you get 2 players on the wii?  I get an error when I go into team survival saying I need 2 players, but can't find out where to add a player.

Comment: Are you aware of what "2 players" IS? it sounds by your question as if the concept has flown over your head, the idea is to play with a friend, a sibling, ect, using a second controller. Do you have a second wii remote and additional accessories (maybe another portal) you need for Skylanders in order to play 2 players?

Comment: Yes I have two controllers and only need one portal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using both traditional remotes with nunchucks plugged in!!!! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is either two things.

**Another remote has not been turned on.**

If you haven't turned on another Wii remote, do so. If it is unresponsive or it is from another Wii system, you might want to sync the remote to the Wii system.

[Instructions on how to sync a remote to the Wii](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail./a_id/2815/p/604/c/567)

**A second Skylander has not been placed on the Portal.**

If an additional Skylander figure has not been placed on the Portal, do so. This is probably the reason why the second player has not shown up.